# Mongoose filter a subdocument via its dynamic key during an aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to have filtered `terms` object where the elements of `keys` array need to examine if they match any sub-key of the `terms` object. I need to achieve that with **aggregation** operation, I will be doing some other operations.

The keys of the objects are hashed values, they will be dynamic. So, I need to somehow loop through `keys` and check if any of the sub-key of `terms` matches.

```
{
    terms: {
        "hash1": {
            "some": "value",
            // ..
        },
        "hash2": {
            "another": "value",
            // ..
        }
    },
    keys: ["hash2"]
}
```

The desired output would be:

```
{
    filteredTerms: [
        {
        "another": "value",
        // ..
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `aggregation`. I've done the job in this way.

First use `$objectToArray` to transform `terms` field into an array and get the key values.

Then use `$project` and `$filter` to get those documents where the object key exists into `keys` field.

At last, using `$set` you can replace the array with the value returned previously.

The query is like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    /*This stage is to get the key 'hashX' */
    "$project": { "terms": { "$objectToArray": "$terms" }, "keys": 1 }
  },
  {
    /* Here filter the key where exists in $keys array */
    "$project": { "filteredTerms": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$terms",
          "as": "array",
          "cond": { "$in": [ "$$array.k", "$keys" ] } } }
    }
  },
  {
    /* This stage set the the values into the field */
    "$set": { "filteredTerms": "$filteredTerms.v" }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t7zxohSdLoE) where I've added another value.